# Rails and Globalize - join translation table of related model in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, has-many-through, globalize

I want to order some records of a model that has a relation to another model (with translated attributes). Here an example:

1. I have a model **Project**
2. I have a model **Task**
3. I have the relation **Project** *has_many* **Tasks**
4. The model **Task** has attribute *name* globalized (on *task_translations* table)

Now, I want to order all projects by its tasks name. How can I write this scope? How can I join the translation table in Rails like method *with_translation* in gem globalize (https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/eccb924ac9641b52399f22525b0e3ec004739f4c/lib/globalize/active_record/class_methods.rb) but from related object **Project**?

```
> Project.all.joins(:tasks) ... (how to include task translation table) ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the `task_translations` is directly related to `tasks` and you can query it like so:

```
Project.joins(tasks: :translations)
```

Comment: And this is how you access the table `Project.joins(tasks: :translations).where("task_translations.name = ?", "todo") }`

Comment: @Epigene What about different locales?

Comment: @TalhaShoaib Assuming the locale is a column in `task_translations` table, an additional `.where("task_translations.locale = ?", locale)` should do it.